# Print a variable inside a variable

Tags: python

```
line0 = "hello"
line1 = "stack"
line2 = "overflow"
linenum = 1
for x in range(3):
    linenum = "line%d"%(x)
    print(linenum)
```

I would like to print hello stack overflow but it just prints: line0 line1 line2

Comment: "line%d" gets formatted to the string "line0" and not the variable line0. I've added an answer showing how to do that

Answer (score 1):

You are constructing variable names dynamically. You can get the global namespace dictionary and look them up from there.

```
line0 = "hello"
line1 = "stack"
line2 = "overflow"
linenum = 1
for x in range(3):
    linenum = globals()["line%d"%(x)]
    print(linenum)
```

Its common to use a list or dictionary to hold data you want to lookup by way of an index or name. For instance,

```
lines = ["hello", "stack", "overflow"]
```

Whether that's the best thing in this case is a design decision for you.

Comment: This Worked:

line0 = "hello"
line1 = "stack"
line2 = "overflow"
lines = [line0, line1, line2]
ans = ""
for x in range(len(lines)):
    ans += lines[x]
print(ans)

Credit to @FoundABetterName

Comment: This works, and it's probably the most precise answer to the question. But plucking things out of the global namespace is not usually the best solution. I hope OP will think a bit more and come up with a solution the the actual problem being faced that doesn't do this.

Comment: @MrKeviscool - Right, that is much like my example of `lines = ["hello", "stack", "overflow"]` except that it also binds the values to variables `line0`, `line1` and `line2`. If you don't need those variable names in your program, then you wouldn't do that extra step. In the short example given, its not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
line0 = "hello"
line1 = "stack"
line2 = "overflow"
lines = [line0, line1, line2]
ans = ""
for x in range(len(lines)):
    ans += lines[x]
print(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution. I have used the `list` here. Hope it helps.

```
lines_list = ["hello", "stack", "overflow"]
for i in range(0, len(lines_list)):
    print (lines_list[i]),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
line0 = "hello "
line1 = "stack "
line2 = "overflow "
linenum = line0 + line1 +line2
for x in range(1):
    print(linenum)
```

Output:
hello stack overflow.

Here is one way to print hello stack overflow.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Use list is best practice.

```
lines=['hello','stack','overflow']
print(*lines, sep=' ')
```

If you don't want use list then try this.

```
line0 = "hello"
line1 = "stack"
line2 = "overflow"
for x in range(3):
    exec(f'print(line{x},end=" ")')
```